# How can I stop my whole screen from flashing white on errors?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Whenever I access Terminal and press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Delete ⌫</kbd> my screen flashes white.

It also happens when Chrome's <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> returns no results.

Have I somehow messed up my settings?

I already verified that `Universal Access` » `Hearing` » `Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs` was unchecked. I've tried toggling the setting and still get the flash animation.

Comment: Some things you can do to try and isolate the issue is reboot in safe mode (shift key) to test. Also make a new user and log out of the broken user and into the new user to see if it's something local to your account. Good luck hunting this down. If you do - go ahead and answer it with what you found. It might be something unique that we can't reproduce well.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think it's an issue to do with the alert sounds. If you go to the Sound > Sound Effects menu, and click on any of the alert sounds, nothing plays. The Universal Access panel knows that you're not hearing anything so resorts to flashing the screen as an override. I think this is something to do with SoundFlower as I uninstalled that just before this problem began manifesting itself.

Comment: I wanted to enable the screen flashing on bell on this work Mac, but couldn't remember how I've enabled it in the past. So even though this post is asking the opposite question, it still answered mine. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 44):

As discovered by [corwin.amber](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/73848/corwin-amber) in [another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205836/11337), the problem sometimes lies with a dead coreaudiod and can be fixed with:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

Comment: I can note that this seems more frequent if you use external audio. I personally use the DisplayPort for my audio out to a sound system hooked up through my monitor, and have seen this issue.

Comment: As someone above had put it, I had this exact same behavior "If you go to the Sound > Sound Effects menu, and click on any of the alert sounds, nothing plays. The Universal Access panel knows that you're not hearing anything so resorts to flashing the screen as an override."

And that killall did the trick for me! And fixed the alert in the pane as well!

Comment: For whatever reason, my mac had switched audio device back to the inbuilt MacBook Pro Speakers and started this screen flashing behavior. Switching back to the HDMI speaker device stopped the flashing without killing coreaudiod or rebooting.

Answer (score 43):

This sounds ridiculously simple, but it has worked for me in the past. Try checking and then unchecking `Universal Access` » `Hearing` » `Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs` -- this really sounds like that is the behavior in question, and sometimes setting it and the unsetting it resets to the desired behavior. (Note, this might be under `Audio` in newer versions of Mac OS.)

This basically checks that the preference file can be written to have a no then a yes and will clear up all sorts of minor issues in how apps can store preferences. The next step is to delete (or move to the desktop) the preference file for the affected application. In this case, the system stores this flash preference here:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist`

At this point, you might need to expand to see if rebooting, trying a new user account helps isolate the issue.

Comment: Restarted. It works now lol.

Comment: @carlos, if the answer helps, please mark it as accepted so others can benefit.

Comment: Location/Wording changed over the years: Now (Catalina) it's in `System Preferences` -> `Accessibility` -> `Audio`

Comment: Looks like doing this [added the previously-nonexistent key `flashScreen` to `com.apple.universalaccess.plist`](https://gist.github.com/ijoseph/7e953b17b86b392b1d223f4cb5aacad1), which might explain what the issue was before (perhaps if the key didn't exist, macOS defaulted to flashing).

Answer (score 10):

Restart. This happens to me periodically. Restarting always fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be the only thing that fixes it for me too.

Comment: Restarting fixes this for me intermittently.

Comment: Again the default fix: "Did you try turn it off and on again?"

Answer (score 6):

```
rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
```

This will fix it every time.  Maybe someday apple will fix the bug that keeps corrupting `com.apple.universalaccess.plist`.

Comment: OS X 10.8.5 does not have a ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist.
Is there an equivalent file of another name?

Comment: @Scott I am on 10.8.5 and I have it

Comment: Does not work for me, 10.10.5 (14F27)

Comment: Worked for me on 10.10.4

Answer (score 5):

Uncheck the 'visual bell' box in the preferences for your terminal style.

Terminals->Preferences->Profiles->Advanced:

Bell:
Audible bell
Visual bell <>

Answer (score 5):

Reposting here from [another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205836/11337) as suggested by [David Wolever](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/11337/david-wolever).

In a similar situation, I was about to give up and reboot, but then I found that restarting the **audio** daemon resolves the issue:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

The symptom was: in the "Sound Effects" system setting panel, selecting alert sounds didn't do anything (usually it triggers a preview of the selected effect). My guess is that OS X fails to play an alert sound, and falls back to the visual cue.

Comment: `sudo killall coreaudiod` is the solution of one/third of my macOS problems.. ; another third is solved with `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sleep 2;` 

Answer (score 4):

Aware this is an old thread, but today I realized this was happening since updating to Mac OS Catalina, so hopefully, this can help others.

user20095's comment above helped me to solve it.

In Sound > Sound Effects, the output device for alerts (HDMI monitor) was set differently to my main audio output (Headphone port). As this selected output was muted, no alert sounds were playing, therefore Mac OS defaulted to flashing the screen - even though the screen flash option was unchecked in Accessibility.

Comment: Thank you! OMG this was driving me insane, and this was the fix for me. I never even realized it was possible to output effects differently from, um, "Output". Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it off in System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio > Flash screen

Comment: Works for Catalina 

Answer (score 0):

Could have to do with your audio alert set-up. This worked for me in OS X Mavericks. Under apple > preferences > assessability > audio:
uncheck "Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs".

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is a [duplicate answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25607/) but with a different way of accessing the option in a newer version of OS X. To clarify someone else's answer, use the 'edit' or 'improve this answer' button below the post that you wish to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Checking and then unchecking Universal Access » Hearing » Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs works pretty well. Seems there is some bug. Apple need to solve this issue.