# Bell causes entire screen to flash white

Tags: audio, macos, accessibility

I have an old-ish iMac where the sound has stopped working:

[image]

which I'm not really too fussed about - it doesn't get used for a whole lot of stuff.

The only really annoying part is that it seems like every time the OS wants to play a bell, it sees that there's no sound available so it flashes the entire screen white.

I've checked [another SE post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25605/how-can-i-stop-my-whole-screen-from-flashing-white-on-errors) which recommended checking "Accessibility > Audio > Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs" and trying to enable then disable it - done that, and had no luck. I've also removed `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist` and restarted, that hasn't helped either.

As another answer on the other post suggested, I've also tried running `sudo killall coreaudiod` with no joy.

Does anyone else have any idea how I can get rid of the white flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have a broken audio card and VMs apparently don't work with a virtual sound device (pun not intended but it got one - maybe I made a mistake installing Soundflower) I can't really prove it, but the following should work:

- Download [Soundflower 2.0b2](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/download/2.0b2/Soundflower-2.0b2.dmg) (for 10.8, 10.9, 10.10)
- or download [Soundflower 1.6.3](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/download/2.0b2/Soundflower-2.0b2.dmg) (tested with 10.7)
- or download and compile the [Soundflower sources](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower)
- Install Soundflower and reboot your Mac
- Set the Soundflower device as default audio output for alerts/sound effects with the Audio-MIDI-Setup tool (found in /Applications/Utilities).

  [image]

Comment: Awesome, that's sorted it :) Still no sound, which is totally fine, but no more annoying screen flash either. I can't award the bounty for 19 hours, so when that time's up, it's all yours

Comment: @Joe ;-)  To get the sound working again you have to add a second question. If the the audio chip isn't blown it should be possible. Please add your [iMac model](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/index-imac.html) and the version of your current OS X.

Comment: Don't worry - not worth the effort for the use it gets. It was just infuriating to have it flashing every time I clicked somewhere I shouldn't :P